# rust application VSZ keeps growing

Tags: rust

I have a rust application and it gets uploaded files from user and saves it to disk.
i am using axum and tokio. here is the part that i think have a problem.

in my request handler i get uploaded files and save it to disk like this:

```rust
        while let Some(chunk) = field.next().await {
            f.write_all(&chunk.map_err(|_| StatusCode::INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)?)
                .await
                .map_err(|_| StatusCode::INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)?;
        }
```

my app allocates memory for this operation but it looks like the memory does not go back to os. here is my `docker top` result after 5 days of server running:

[image: docker top]

i ran `heaptrack` and it said i have no leak.
i also used `valgrind` and it said i have no leak.

Comment: What's `f`? A file you're keeping open? Why would it not grow if you're continuously writing to it?

Comment: It creates a file `f` and save user uploaded file. And it stops when it saved all files

Comment: Show that code, we need a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @cafce25 I think I found the problem. I didn't close the file after writing was done. Thanks